# TIFF to BufferedImage - JAI on eclipse for Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, osx-mavericks, tiff, jai

I've searched everywhere and am thoroughly confused. Trying to read a TIFF file in as a `BufferedImage`. I've imported both:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.media.jai.*;
```

However, my `BufferedImage` types are still reading as null when the file is passed through and they are created. Is there anything else I need to make sure is there? Through other posts I've seen that JAI might not be fully supported on macs? Running mavericks. Any direction here would be nice.

A small example section of my code here:

```
File f = new File(*file path posted here*);
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(f);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle only provides [endstates](http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/) for windows (32 bit), linux, and solaris.

Comment: would this update from apple automatically update my environment in eclipse, or are other steps needed? thank you.